Are there problems where the optimal policy is stochastic?
I know that in a MDP there always exists a unique optimal deterministic policy. Does a statement like this also exist for optimal stochastic policies? Is there also always a unique optimal stochastic policy? Can it be better than the optimal deterministic policy?

Sutton and Barto give an example of an MDP where the optimal stochastic policy strictly dominates the best deterministic one, should answer all your questions

